# Cannot pull cloned repo from remote github

Tags: git, github

I've cloned a repo from github. now I've a local repo but when I try to update from remote with git pull, I get the error, that

```
Your configuration specifies to merge with the ref 'release/3.3.0'
from the remote, but no such ref was fetched.
```

How can I change the remote ref?

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you're fetching a tag that no longer exists.

Comment: Maybe `git fetch -p` before pull will solve your problem, but I if you have modifications on that branch I don't know what will happen.

Answer (score 0):

If I call explicit

```
git pull origin master
```

it worked.